# How to identify DOM html code changes due to a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've a Google Chrome javascript plug-in that modifies the HTML code of a page. But when I click on "view source", on the page, the code isn't modified (though the page displays modified).
I think the plugin modifies the DOM after the page is loaded.

How can I get, via javascript (on the page, not on the plugin), the whole HTML -modified- code, and save it in a variable?

Comment: Might be helpful to mention why you are looking for the entire modified HTML string. There may be a more efficient way to accomplish what you’d like to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `outerHTML` of the `<html>` tag:

```
var currentSourceCode = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
```